Firebase prepare domain namn with SSL before changing my DNS record
I have created an app in Firebase hosting. In a few days I want to change the DNS record for my domain name and point it to the Firebase app I just created.
If I do that, I will have downtime until the certificate is automatically created and I want to avoid this by letting firebase generate the SSL certificate in advance.
I do see this message:

One or more of Hosting's HTTP GET request for the ACME challenge failed: xxx.xxx.xx.xx Not found

I tried to add the domain in Firebase and then go to the advance tab to find the TXT data. The problem is that I can see the text "Prepare Domain" and then the button "Verify" but there is no records.
I don't know if the reason is because the domain I'm trying to prepare, already have a CNAME to another domain.
Do you know if there is a way for me to let Firebase prepare the SSL to avoid downtime when I move?
